# Concept behind double recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, lambda

Could someone explain me how this double recursion works? I need to understand the order of actions (i.e how this algorithm works) I know how works the ordinary (single) recursion. For instance, something like this:

```
Q=lambda n:n>3 and Q(n-3)or n
print(Q(10))
```

so, while n>3 (True in our case), we make a transit to our recursion and subtract 3, then we got 7 -> it's more than 3, so we repeat our actions (cus it's still True) and now we have 4 and it's still more than 3, so we repeat it again and now we have 1. 1 is less than 3 and now it's False. In False or n -> we get n, so the result of this single recursion will be 1 (n=1).
It's absolutely clear for me.

BUT I'm completely in stuck with double recursion. I'm trying to get the print but so far I have no idea what is going on here. Please help. Point to the order of actions at this function.

```
F=lambda n:n>3 and F(n-3)+F(n-2)or n
print(F(10))
```

Comment: `F(n-3)` will be calculated, then `F(n-2)` will be calculated.  Then their sum will be calculated. If you're not familiar with the idea of a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), you should do some research on that topic, which is critical to the order of function execution.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The second example doesn't seem significantly different from the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always consider the recursion stack as if it is a Tree. If you have double recursion then consider that you have a binary tree i.e. there will be two branches of each node in the recursion stack.

If you have single recursion then consider it as a `skewed Tree`, if you have `triple recursion` then consider as if it is a `3-ary Tree`, and so on. For `n` recursions consider a `n-ary` Tree.

Example:

`F=lambda n:n>3 and F(n-3)+F(n-2)`

let, n = 10;

```
          10
        /   \
       7      8
      / \    / \
     4  5    5  6
    / \ /\  / \ /\
   1  2 2 3 2 3 3 4 -----> returns here except last right node (i.e. 4)
                  /\
                 1  2 -----> returns here because its the base case (as n < 3)
```

So, the output is `1+2+2+3+2+3+3+1+2` i.e. `19`

Also, you can always print out the function calls to understand the recursion more properly.

Example, I have written the same program without using lambda where I am printing the function call stack.

Program

```
F = lambda n:n>3 and F(n-3)+F(n-2) or n

def indent(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        print '    '*i,

# the second argument is just passed to print the apt space before the print statement
def fun(n, rec_cnt):
    indent(rec_cnt)
    print 'fun(' + str(n) + ')'
    if n <= 3:
        return n
    else:
        return fun(n-3, rec_cnt+1) + fun(n-2, rec_cnt+1)


# print F(10)

print fun(10, 0)
```

You can see the output below:

```
fun(10)
 fun(7)
      fun(4)
               fun(1)
               fun(2)
      fun(5)
               fun(2)
               fun(3)
 fun(8)
      fun(5)
               fun(2)
               fun(3)
      fun(6)
               fun(3)
               fun(4)
                            fun(1)
                            fun(2)
19
```